# Passing value from jsp to servlet but servlet is not available

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea

I am using intellij idea 14 to create a web app using servlet and jsp but whenever i try to pass value from jsp there is error as

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Books/BookSaleAuctionServlet

type Status report

message /Books/BookSaleAuctionServlet

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
```

Myfiles are :
index.jsp

```
<form method= "get" action="Books/BookSaleAuctionServlet">
  UserName : <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  Address : <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
  Contact : <input type="tel" name="contactNo" id="contactNo">
  Email : <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    Password : <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
    <input type="submit" name="save">
```

and there is servlet as `BookSaleAuctionServlet` inside `Books` package and it contains

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");
        String contact = request.getParameter("contact");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        System.out.println("check 1");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class not found "+ e);
        }
        System.out.println("JDBC Class found");
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/logins", "root", "");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery
                    ("CREATE TABLE members (user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n" +
                            "    username varchar(45) NOT NULL,\n" +
                            "    password varchar(45) NOT NULL,\n" +
                            "    contact varchar(45) NOT NULL,\n" +
                            "    email varchar(45) NOT NULL,\n" +
                            "    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)\n" +
                            "); ");        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQL exception occured" + e);
        }
        System.out.print("done with databases");
    }
```

and `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>BookSaleAuctionServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Books.BookSaleAuctionServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BookSaleAuctionServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/bookSaleAuction</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

please help

Comment: You should read what `<url-pattern>` means in `<servlet-mapping>` configuration in web.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change
`action="Books/BookSaleAuctionServlet"` 
to `action="/bookSaleAuction"`